# Can two collect be used with the same StateFlow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I am trying to understand the use of flow in Kotlin and I was trying different codes, in particular I was with this method:

```kotlin
val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(0) 

private fun stateFlowWithContinueCollect() {
    runBlocking {

        launch {
            repeat(10) {
                delay(1000)
                stateFlow.value = stateFlow.value + 1
            }
        }

        stateFlow.collect { value ->
            println("Actual value is $value")
            if (value == 6) {
                continueInSameFlow()
            }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun continueInSameFlow() {
    stateFlow.collect {
        println("Im in the second collect, value is $it")
    }
}
```

I understand that when I am in the first collect, it will be receiving values until it enters the second collect when value is equal to 6, so as it is a suspend function, will stay in until it is finished.

Is there any way for two collects to take data from the same StateFlow at the same time, or does that not make sense?

I have tried putting one collect under another, but apart from Android Studio giving me a warning that it does not make sense, I see that it only executes one collect but not the second one.

Comment: What is your actual question? You want to nest a collect call inside another collect call on the same flow? What is the point of doing this?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sorry, I don't know why it has been published halfway and the question was not there. Now I have edited it.

Comment: So you want to collect twice in parallel, but the second collector only starts after a value of 6 appears?

Comment: @Tenfour04 even if you remove the if, it will print the first message of the first collect and then enter the second collect until it finishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Summary

Replace your call to `continueInSameFlow()` with `launch { continueInSameFlow() }` so you're running the second collector asynchronously in another coroutine. Collecting suspends the coroutine until the flow completes, but StateFlows never complete, so you're causing the first collection to hang.

#### Detailed explanation

`flow.collect()` suspends the coroutine to wait for the flow to complete emitting all the items it will ever emit. StateFlows are infinite (as are SharedFlows and many cold Flows as well.)

Therefore, if you do something like this:

```
scope.launch {
    someInfiniteFlow.collect {
        println(it)
    }

    println("Hello") // unreachable code
}
```

then `"Hello"` will never be printed, because `collect` never returns. It will suspend forever, always waiting for the next item to be emitted and then running the lambda again for each one.

So of course, if you put another collect call in place of the `println()`, that will never be reached either. It doesn't matter if it's the same flow or a different one. Whatever you're doing down there is unreachable code.

```
scope.launch {
    someInfiniteFlow.collect {
        println(it)
    }

    anyFlow.collect { // unreachable code
        println(it)
    }
}
```

In your sample code, this same principle applies. When you start collecting an infinite flow inside your outer `collect` lambda, you are calling a function that will suspend forever. Therefore, that iteration of your lambda will never return, so it will never be called again with another item to process.

---

Therefore, if you want to collect flows in parallel (whether or not they are the same flow), you must do it in separate coroutines:

```
scope.launch {
    someInfiniteFlow.collect {
        println(it)
    }
}

scope.launch {
    anyFlow.collect {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

For this reason, it is very common that a coroutine that collects a flow doesn't do anything besides collecting that flow. It's so common that there is a `launchIn` operator for Flows to help make code easier to read (less nested indentation). This is equivalent to the above:

```
someInfiniteFlow.onEach {
    println(it)
}.launchIn(scope)

anyFlow.onEach {
    println(it)
}.launchIn(scope)
```

Here is how I would rewrite the code from your question so the first collection is not interrupted by the second one that starts after "6" is emitted:

```
val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(0) 

private fun stateFlowWithContinueCollect() {
    runBlocking {

        launch {
            repeat(10) {
                delay(1000)
                stateFlow.value = stateFlow.value + 1
            }
        }

        stateFlow
            .onEach { value ->
                println("Actual value is $value")
            }
            .launchIn(this)

        stateFlow
            .dropWhile { it != 6 }
            .onEach {
                println("Im in the second collect, value is $it")
            }
            .launchIn(this)
    }
}
```

The `launchIn` calls are launching child coroutines of the `runBlocking`'s CoroutineScope instead of synchronously collecting the flows directly in the `runBlocking` coroutine.

If you want to do it your way, you can. In your code, wrap the call to `continueInSameFlow()` in `launch { }` so it is collected asynchronously to the first collector.

Note that either way you do it, since you're collecting infinite flows, your outer function `stateFlowWithContinueCollect()` can never return.

Comment: It has become much clearer to me, thank you very much, I mark it as an answer.